# Problem showing clon of gltf-model using model.clone()

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, clone

My main purpose was to assign: let clone = model.clone(); somewhere in global scope.
But then I recived a error of "cannot read property of undefined reading model" or something simillar, due to that it was assigned in the gltf-loader-functions scope, I assume. Then I tried assigning model in global scope using: let model; before the gltf.loaderfunction still receving the same error. Unable of understanding why model still was undefined in global scope I tried put the following code in the gltf-loader-function, which led to the error disapering from the console output. But the clone was still absent on the screen.

```
clone = model.clone(); clone.position.set(0, 0, 0); scene.add(clone);
```

```
   const loader = new GLTFLoader();
   loader.load('stegosaurs_SStenops.glb', (gltf) => {
   gltf.scene.position.set(0, 40, 130);
   gltf.scene.visible = true;
   model = gltf.scene;
   scene.add(model);
   /* let skeleton = new SkeletonHelper(model);
   scene.add( skeleton );
   const { animations } = gltf;
   mixer = new AnimationMixer(model);
   mixer.timeScale = 0.5;
   const animationAction = mixer.clipAction(animations[0]);
   const animationAction2 = mixer.clipAction(animations[1]);
   const animationAction3 = mixer.clipAction(animations[7]);
   animationAction.play();
   animationAction.loop = LoopOnce;
   animationAction2.loop = LoopOnce;
   animationAction3.repetitions = 100;
   mixer.addEventListener('finished',function(e){
    if(e.action._clip.name === 'attack1'){
      animationAction2.reset();
      animationAction2.play();
    }
    else if(e.action._clip.name === 'attack2'){
      animationAction3.reset();
      animationAction3.play();
    }
    else if(e.action._clip.name === 'walk1') {
      animationAction.reset();
      animationAction.play();
    }*/
   })
  } );
```

Comment: Read the docs: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=utils#examples/en/utils/SkeletonUtils.clone